# re.sub not working for a particular regex pattern

Tags: python, regex

I am using following code :

`re.sub(inputpattern,outputpattern, currentline)`

in the above code  , i am reading the value of outputpattern from csv , whose value is :

```
\\1-\\2-\\3-\\4
```

I am reading it like below :

`outputpattern =  row['PREFIX_1_WRT_FMT']`

I have also tried :

`outputpattern =  "'"+ row['PREFIX_1_WRT_FMT'] +"'"`

The problem is that it is not treating it as proper format , but if I hard code it like below it works fine :

`re.sub(inputpattern,'\\1-\\2-\\3-\\4', currentline)`

Comment: How does the csv file get written? It looks like `outputpattern` has **double** backslashes in it. What do you see when you open the csv file in a text editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to escape the backslashes if you have it as a literal string.

```
"\\1-\\2-\\3-\\4"
```

If you read it from an input you don't have to do that.  You need to change the pattern inside the CSV to be like \1-\2-\3-\4

You could also use the raw string if you dislike escaping every char when using literal string, by prefixing you string with the letter r.

```
r"\1-\2-\3-\4"
```

Comment: @IshuGupta: If Meitham's answer solved your problem, please mark it as Accepted (the big check-mark).